¿Porqué se redirecciona en mi request del BeautifulSoup?
desde hace tiempo saco info de loterias y apuestas, con BeautifulSoup, pero desde ayer, me marca este mensaje:
<html><head>
<title>Access Denied</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Access Denied</h1>

You don't have permission to access "http://www.loteriasyapuestas.es/es/resultados" on this server.<p>
Reference #18.5b757b5c.1713456671.3780b6ea
<p>https://errors.edgesuite.net/18.5b757b5c.1713456671.3780b6ea</p>
</p></body>
</html>

Desde mi código no he tocado nada, por lo que asumo que puede ser que hayan modificado algo en la suya. Mi código es muy simple:
urlResultados ='https://www.loteriasyapuestas.es/es/resultados'
cabecera = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(urlResultados,headers=cabecera)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
print (soup)
if soup.find ('p',id='qa_ultResult-BONO-fecha') != None:
    f = datetime.strptime(soup.find ('p',id='qa_ultResult-BONO-fecha').text,'%d/%m/%Y')
    print (f'{f}')

Agradeceria una ayuda.

El código está bien, parece que bloquearon ese user-agent, no estaras haciendo muchas peticiones?

Esta programado todos los dias de 22:00 a 02:00 cada 10 minutos. Pero ya llevo unos dias sin usarlo y sigue como bloqueado. Tengo otros pequeños scripts manuales para la misma pagina y tampoco me funcionan, con el mismo error. ¿Alguna solución?

Podrias ir cambiando de user-agent si te los siguen bloqueando (aca hay una lista de los más usados), usar retrasos aleatorios, por ejemplo, de 10 a 15 min, o tambien usar proxies para que cada peticion salga con una IP diferente.

Tomo nota de cada una de las cosas. Estaba buscando como sacar el user-agent de esa pagina y me estaba constando un poco.

Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda y por los consejos. Pregunta cerrada.

Prueba accediendo desde el navegador, si es que puedes acceder, puede que llegue a ser un problema en el header, quizas te falta mandar una cookie o algún parámetro no es válido, si no puedes acceder desde tu web, puede que te bloquearon la IP, usa una vpn con OpenVPN en Python. Suerte

Gracias, eso ya lo hice antes de exponer mi pregunta. Con la ayuda de @Mady, y un poco mas de "lectura" lo solucioné.
